# How do I use two consecutive elements of a deque at once in a for loop?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, deque

I have to process element from a deque (first to last), but at each iteraton I need to use one element and the next too. So I'm trying to write a for loop that starts with mydeque.begin() and finishes at mydeque[mydeque.size()-1]. Also; I would like to know if my iterator deque::iterator it has a next method (it->next()), to make operations like *it - *it->next(). Thank you very much.

Comment: Why not simply use indexes instead of iterators? That should make the loop trivial.

Comment: `next(it)` returns the next iterator in C++11.

Comment: If you *must* use iterators, then `std::deque` have [random access iterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) which means you can do e.g. `iter != std::end(the_deque) - 1` and `*(iter + 1)` (and also `iter[1]`) and `iter += 2`.

Comment: By the way, is the deque *guaranteed* to have an even number of values? Can there ever be an uneven number of values in it? The correctness of the answer given by s1h depends very much on this.

Comment: Actually iter += 2 won't do it, because I use the present element and the next. In the first iteration I use element 1 and 2, in the second the elements 2 and 3 and so on. Thanks for the comment

Comment: Thanks Pete, I'll try it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
std::deque<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
for(auto i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); i++) {
    auto next = std::next(i);
    std::cout << *i << *next << std::endl;
    if(next==test.end())
      {
       //Do something. This is the last element.
       break;
      }

}
}
```

**EDIT:** Watch out for deques with only one element. Do this by performing a check such as `if(test.begin()==test.end())`.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: My initial solution was indeed a bit error prone and unprecise.

This can easily be done using iterators, see this little example:

```
#include <deque>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::deque<int> test = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
    for(auto i = test.begin(); i != test.end(); ++i) {
        auto next = std::next(i);
        if(next != test.end()) {
            std::cout << *i << " " << *next << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

You can simply increment the iterator by 2 and use [std::next](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/next/) to also pick the following item (since the offset of std::next defaults to 1).

Comment: You do realize this might skip the last element?

Comment: Actually iter += 2 won't do it, because I use the present element and the next. In the first iteration I use element 1 and 2, in the second the elements 2 and 3 and so on. Thanks for the answer